# jQuery DataTables multipe firing of onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am firing off multiple click methods from my jQuery DataTable. (I only want one)

```
//First set the table into a datatable
$("#mytable").datatable(/*in here I define the click*/);
//Then hide the first 2 columns for admin purposes
$("#mytable").fnSetColumnVis( 0, false );
$("#mytable").fnSetColumnVis( 1, false );
```

When I comment out the bottom two lines, everything works fine, but if not, the **click** function gets called 3 times.

Comment: Please show us how you defined the click.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the $("").click(function(){}); method then somewhere your adding the function multiple times. For a easy way to fix that use

```
 $("").off('click').click(function(){});
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why then if I comment out those other two it doesn't fire multiple times?

Comment: I don't think you've supplied enough code for me to know ?